# How to make a video with partially in low quality

Tags: video-processing, video-encoding

Is it possible to make a video with some parts in high quality (e.g. some important part) and other parts in low quality?

Here is my idea:

1. Decode the video
2. Get each frame of the video and do something on the frame to reduce quality (How would I go about doing this?)
3. Encode it back

I am new to handling video.  Don't know if this works or not.  Please tell me more. Thanks.

Comment: It's certainly *possible*, the question is whether you have the tools to do it conveniently.

Comment: possible to do this by using ffmpeg??

Comment: With the library, probably; with the command-line tool, I would doubt it. Film studios that compress films for DVD have tools that let you adjust the compression even for subregions of the image. Maybe you can find out which software packages there are.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what most codecs would do already when using variable bitrate and varying the automatic key frame rate.  Of course, the algorithm would be deciding what the "important" parts are.

For your example process, I would go oldschool Pro, trimming and exporting each section, doing a massive smoothing on each "not important" file, then concatenating them again in QuickTime.

Answer (score 0):

If you would use VBR and multiple encoding passes, most codec will do this out of the box (for example DivX, XviD, H.264 and MPEG-2).

Wikipedia has a quite informative article about VBR and multi-pass encoding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_bitrate

Hope this will help you a little bit at least :)